# Is it possible to pass argument to a decorated function?

Tags: python, decorator

I have written the below decorator:

```
import time

def runtime(some_function):   
    def wrapper():
        start = time.time()        
        some_function()         
        runtime = time.time() - start   
        print(runtime)       
    return wrapper              

@runtime
def printing(upper_limit):
    for number in range(upper_limit):
        print(number)

printing(10)
printing(100)
printing(1000)
printing(10000)
```

Why do I get:

> TypeError: wrapper() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

when running the code and how to fix it?

Comment: Yes; you just need to make `wrapper` accept an argument.

Comment: Also look into `functools.wraps`

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `wrapper` accept arguments and pass them to `some_function`. It should also return what `some_function` returns to be more generic.

```
def runtime(some_function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        result = some_function(*args, **kwargs)
        runtime = time.time() - start
        print(runtime)
        return result
    return wrapper
```

Comment: You probably want to have `wrapper` return whatever `some_function` returns as well.

Comment: Indeed. I've updated my answer with a more generic solution.